# Can't Access Variables in IEnumerator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a vr game that uses Raycasting guns, and use them to shoot a ball causing it to explode. I followed some tutorials on how to do it but I also wanted bullet trails on the end causing it to be slower than instant. I found a tutorial on how to add them, but that means that the ball is exploding before the trail gets there. I found a work around for the Particle System spawning at the ball when the trail dies using various bools. But I don't know how to destroy the ball game object when the trail gets to it, so far it just destroys instantly. I've tried to access variables from IEnumerator, such as trying the while(distance > 0), but I think because it is declared in the IEnumerator. If I try it, it just gives me this error: Assets\Scripts\HandGun.cs(97,20): error CS0103: The name 'distance' does not exist in the current context

I don't completely know what I'm doing, so if any of this is just bad I would love some feedback on how to make it better!
Cheers!

My Code:

```
public ParticleSystem desVer;

ActionBasedController controller;

[SerializeField]
private ParticleSystem ShootingSystem;
[SerializeField]
private Transform BulletSpawnPoint;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject ImpactParticleSystem;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject BallExplode;
[SerializeField]
private TrailRenderer BulletTrail;
[SerializeField]
private float ShootDelay = 0.1f;
[SerializeField]
private float Speed = 100;
[SerializeField]
private LayerMask Mask;
[SerializeField]
private bool BouncingBullets;
[SerializeField]
private float BounceDistance = 10f;

public bool triggerDown;
public bool didHitButton;
public bool dontGoYet;
public bool didHitBall;

public float triggerInput;

private float LastShootTime;

public void Start(){
    controller = GetComponent<ActionBasedController>();
    
}

public void Update(){
    triggerInput = controller.activateAction.action.ReadValue<float>();
    if(triggerInput == 1){

        Shoot();
    }

    
}

private void CheckTrigger(){
    if (triggerInput == 1){
        triggerDown = true;
        Debug.Log("Trigger On");
    }
    else{
        triggerDown = false;
    }
}

public void Shoot()
{
    if (LastShootTime + ShootDelay < Time.time)
    {

        ShootingSystem.Play();

        Vector3 direction = transform.forward;
        TrailRenderer trail = Instantiate(BulletTrail, BulletSpawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

        if (Physics.Raycast(BulletSpawnPoint.position, direction, out RaycastHit hit, float.MaxValue, Mask))
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnTrail(trail, hit.point, hit.normal, BounceDistance, true));

            
            //Must be declared here because it's declared by hitting the game object
            Breakable isBreaking = hit.transform.GetComponent<Breakable>();
            if(isBreaking != null){
                isBreaking.Break();
                //desVer.Play();
                //Instantiate(desVer);
                //Debug.Log("It should break!");
                didHitButton = true;
                didHitBall = true;
            }



            GunButton gunButton = hit.transform.GetComponent<GunButton>();
            if(gunButton != null){
                gunButton.HitButton();
                didHitButton = true;
            }

            BallResetButton ballResetButton = hit.transform.GetComponent<BallResetButton>();
            if(ballResetButton != null){
                ballResetButton.HitButton();
                didHitButton = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnTrail(trail, BulletSpawnPoint.position + direction * 100, Vector3.zero, BounceDistance, false));
        }

        LastShootTime = Time.time;
    }
}

public IEnumerator SpawnTrail(TrailRenderer Trail, Vector3 HitPoint, Vector3 HitNormal, float BounceDistance, bool MadeImpact)
{
    Vector3 startPosition = Trail.transform.position;
    Vector3 direction = (HitPoint - Trail.transform.position).normalized;

    float distance = Vector3.Distance(Trail.transform.position, HitPoint);
    float startingDistance = distance;

    while (distance > 0)
    {
        Trail.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, HitPoint, 1 - (distance / startingDistance));
        distance -= Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        

        yield return null;
    }

    if(distance <= 0){
        dontGoYet = true;
    }
    else{
        dontGoYet = false;
    }

    Trail.transform.position = HitPoint;

    if (MadeImpact)
    {   
        if(didHitButton == true){
            if(didHitBall == true){
                GameObject explodeGo = Instantiate(BallExplode, HitPoint, Quaternion.identity);
                Destroy(explodeGo, 1f);
                didHitBall = false;
            }
            didHitButton = false;
        }
        else{
            GameObject impactGo = Instantiate(ImpactParticleSystem, HitPoint, Quaternion.LookRotation(HitNormal));
            Destroy(impactGo, 1f);
        }



        if (BouncingBullets && BounceDistance > 0)
        {
            Vector3 bounceDirection = Vector3.Reflect(direction, HitNormal);

            if (Physics.Raycast(HitPoint, bounceDirection, out RaycastHit hit, BounceDistance, Mask))
            {
                yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnTrail(
                    Trail,
                    hit.point,
                    hit.normal,
                    BounceDistance - Vector3.Distance(hit.point, HitPoint),
                    true
                ));
            }
            else
            {
                yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnTrail(
                    Trail,
                    HitPoint + bounceDirection * BounceDistance,
                    Vector3.zero,
                    0,
                    false
                ));
            }
        }
    }

    Destroy(Trail.gameObject, Trail.time);
}
```

}
"

Comment: Why don't you just declare these variables that you need to access as private variables from the HandGun.cs (without SerializeField attribute) ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the SerializedField does differently, it's just what they did in the tutorial so I put it in. Would it effect anything in my script?

Comment: SerializedField will make your private variable visible on the Unity inspector, making easy to tweak values for debugging etc. But it shouldn't affect in your script. My suggestion is to add any variable that you need on different methods from this script as private variables at the top of the script, as you did with "LastShootTime". It is not the best solution, but can help you come up with a simple solution for your problem.

Comment: Oh I see that's cool! good to know! But sounds good thanks!

Comment: Could you point out the line that causes the error ?